# How can I organize data in rows and columns with Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

The base problem is that I have lots of datapoints with normalized names that are just dumped from the server into a file, but I need to organize these datapoints into a file with rows and columns automatically, according to the data they contain (indicated in their normalized names).

---

The original file with all the datapoints comes as follows (these are not the original datapoint tags but rather simplified ones):

```
temp_r301
airflow_r301
temp_r345
airflow_r345
solar_w
solar_e
...
```

As you can see, they all come as one column, so there is one tag per row.

And I want to organize them so that for each state ("temp" as in temperature), I have the corresponding information in the same row, such as:

```
temp_r301 301 airflow_r301 solar_w solar_e     #airflow in 301 and general solar radiation affect temperature (state) in room 301
temp_r345 345 airflow_r345 solar_w solar_e     #airflow in 345 and general solar radiation affect temperature (state) in room 345
```

Of course the lenght of the array can vary so the idea is to make an algorithm that detects the length and organizes the data accordingly. Also, I am aware I will have to use regular expressions to find the matches and define which datapoints are states and which ones inputs, as well as knowing the room to which they belong.

---

So far I have tried the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my @transpose = ();
my @sorted = ();

push(@sorted, [qw(temp_r301 temp_r345)]);
push(@sorted, [qw(301 345)]);
push(@sorted, [qw(airflow_r301 airflow_r345 solar_w solar_e)]);

for my $sorted (@sorted) {
  for my $column (0 .. $#sorted) {
    push(@{$transpose[$column]}, $sorted->[$column]);
  }
}

for my $new_row (@transpose) {
  for my $new_col (@{$new_row}) {
      print "$new_col ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

But this only works fine if all the arrays have the same lenght (not this case).

I also discovered a loop that can be used to store data into matrix form (array of arrays), but still, I can't seem to find a solution to write in the matrix the data from different arrays:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';

my @states = qw(temp_r301 temp_r345);
my @zones = qw(301 345);
my @inputs = qw(airflow_r301 airflow_r345 solar_w solar_e);

my @matrix = ();

for my $x (0 .. $#states) {
    for my $y (0 .. $#inputs) {
        $matrix[$x][$y] = $states[$x];           #of course this only copies the states array and
    }                                            #repeats it for each created array
}

for my $aref (@matrix) {                         #print array of arrays
    say "[ @$aref ],";
}
```

So, knowing that I have all the data dumped into an input file, what would be the best way to sort that data into a matrix? Is there any loop I should give more attention to? Should I be working with arrays?

Comment: What rule determines if an element of `@disturb` should be included for a given state or not?

Comment: (The ones with the numbers are obvious enough, but the ones without any? Should any that might be present, or just ones starting with solar go in?)

Comment: Did you consider a simple CSV (or tab-separated) file? So with columns `temp`, `room #`, `airflow`, `solar_w`, etc (whatever else there may be).  If one of these values is missing for a row then that field for it is just empty

Comment: The rule that determines that has to do with the fact that a disturbance affects the state or not (i.e. airflow into a room affects the room temperature). Of course I will need regular expressions to define that myself. Making a table would be useful but not that useful if you consider that there are more than 20k datapoints. That is why I need to make it into an automatic algorithm.

Comment: So basically what I need is a kick off to know how I could organize the data into arrays of arrays using data that can vary in length. I wanted to ask something basic as a start because I know the program is going to be more complex with regular expressions.

Comment: Edited the post so that it becomes more clear with the example of organized data and the scope of the question.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for responses.  So how about what I asked in a comment above, having a comma/tab delimited file with listed columns?  Then each rows would indeed be what you show as an example, where fields missing from input data would simply be empty. That seems (to me) to be what you need?

Comment: @zdim Yes, that is what I need, and I need to create that kind of table automatically from an input file where all the 20k datapoints are listed in one column, and that is what I understand as an array. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: @Matthias Ok, thank you.  Data manipulation isn't a problem, the question is about understanding what you want done.  So, how does the data in your input file look?  That's not shown in the question, but rather the arrays are (after the data has been read in I presume).  Can you add a few lines from input file(s) to the question? I can work with those arrays of course, but if you actually have files to process then better work with that.

Comment: @zdim I have edited the question so that it shows how the original file with all the tags comes (1 column only). I edited out the arrays so that it is more clear what I want to do. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!  One more question, before I can post some something: in the data you show, how can one tell whether `solar_X` affects room 301, or 345, or both, or yet others... ?  (In this example it comes after 301 and 345 (immediately right after 345), but I doubt that that is a general criterion?)  All other phrases have room numbers in them so they'll be easy to organize but `solar_X` have nothing, and there may well be other phrases/variables without the room number in them.  (That's what @Shawn asked right in the beginning as well.)

Comment: @zdim Of course, that would be a criterion I apply in my program. We should have to see the real data. In this case, we have two rooms from a building located in a city in which the solar radiation coming from the west (solar_w) and from the east (solar_e) affect both rooms in the same amount. So, in a nutshell, all inputs that belong to the weather (outside of the building) affect both rooms (and all the building) equally. Thank you, and hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Since the question clearly refers to a much more rounded problem, and so the details are missing, my posted code is more of a sample, for one way to approach this, which should be reasonably feasible to edit. So let me know how it fares with your actual need.

Comment: @zdim I have been taking a deep look at your code and trying things and it is what I was looking for. Details for this question belong to a more complex problem about big data in buildings related to energy consumption, which I think doesn't belong here, that's why I wanted to put it into more simple words. Next time I will try and be more specific. Thank you very much for your time, it sure helped me out!

Comment: Re [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70867756/589924), you're not trying to *sort*, you're trying to *group*. This is usually done using hashes. The problem is that it's not clear how you want to group. Why is MET+EL____MEA+POW grouped with LI____COM.POS+LI.INT+7.STEP (301,4,9; 345,19,24)? If it's a "that's just the way it is situation", we need to know the list of these associations. Is that what "Is affected by" is? If so, I'd start by creating a hash mapping thing affecting to thing affected. And I'd group the stuff using `push @{ $grouped{$room}{$thing_affected} }, $.;`

Comment: @ikegami That is exactly what the "Is affected by" is meaning. In the example you said it's because this datapoint about electricity consumption (MET+EL____MEA+POW) is only affected by the lighting (LI____COM.POS+LI.INT+7.STEP), because the building is just like that. Thank you for your response and I will try to make a more simple and comprehensible question for the next time about grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details of this problem are still unclear, while explanations did help.  So here is what I'll assume.

I take data to have a piece of information per line. Some contain a tag (description) followed by the room number, and I assume format `tag_rN`, identifying a room number that the tag applies to.

As for others, that don't have the room number, additional processing is needed to decide where that information belongs. The question puts forth only an example of tags that apply to all rooms, related to solar radiation that affects them (see comments), so that's all that's processed.

The fact that some of the data does not neatly classify with a room is what makes organization of the parsed data non-trivial. Since no details are given I merely split it into two hashes, one by room number and another one which structure will depend on specifics.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (%room, %other);
while (<$fh>) { 
    chomp;
    if ( my ($tag, $room_num) = /([^_]+)_r([0-9]+)/ ) {
        $room{$room_num}{$tag} = $_;                  # have room number
    }
    else {                                            # more processing needed
        my ($tag, $value) = parse_line($_);
        push @{ $other{$tag} }, $value;
    }
}
dd \%room; dd \%other; say '';

# Print in CSV format. Header first
my @tags = ( keys %{ $room{ (keys %room)[0] } }, keys %other );
say join ',', 'room', @tags;
foreach my $rnum (keys %room) { 
    say join ',', 
        $rnum, map { $room{$rnum}{$_} // join ' ', @{$other{$_}}  } @tags;
}

sub parse_line {
    my ($line) = @_;
    my ($tag, $value);

    if ($line =~ /solar_w|solar_e/) {   # example from sample data
        $tag   = 'solar';
        $value = $line;
    }
    else { }  # other possibilities

    return $tag, $value;
}
```

The data with the room number is sorted out by the identifying description ("tag") as a key, with the line being its value. Each such key-value pair is in a hashref assigned to each room number.

The data *without* the room number is parsed in a separate sub, with just some token code since no details are given.  Then that is stored in another hash, for easier manipulation (since it's not tied to any one room).

How tags are extracted from data is a bit arbitrary, since it's not specified in the question.

All this is combined into a CSV format.  The above, with the input file from the question and the explanation in comments that the solar radiation from both west and east affects all rooms, prints:

```
{
  301 => { airflow => "airflow_r301", temp => "temp_r301" },
  345 => { airflow => "airflow_r345", temp => "temp_r345" },
}
{ solar => ["solar_w", "solar_e"] }

room,airflow,temp,solar
345,airflow_r345,temp_r345,solar_w solar_e
301,airflow_r301,temp_r301,solar_w solar_e
```

Comment out the line with `dd ...` (from `Data::Dump`) to remove the initial diagnostic prints.  Then the last few lines are the CSV that would go into some file etc.

Some data may be missing for some rooms, and there is yet more data which may not classify so uniformly. Then the fields for those headers will be merrily empty in some rows, as desired.